# React-router v4 route on click Button

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am try to implement a login page in React. I have a login component with 2 input fields (id and password) and a submit button. This button is Material-Ui button component. The button has an onClick method, that check if the id and password are correct. If so, it must route to another component.

```
class Connexion extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        identifiant: '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: ''
    };

    this.checkIdentifiantAndPassaword = this.checkIdentifiantAndPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleIdentifiantChange = this.handleIdentifiantChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
}
handleIdentifiantChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        identifiant: e.target.value
    });
}

handlePasswordChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        password: e.target.value
    });
}
checkIdentifiantAndPassword(e) {
    let { identifiant, password } = this.state;
    if (!identifiant) {
        console.log('check identifiant');
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Identifiant vide ou incorrect.'
        });
        return;
    }
    if (!password) {
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Mot de passe vide ou incorrect.'
        });
        return;
    }
    console.log(this.props);
    this.props.onLogin(true);
    console.log('Succés');
}
render() {
    let { errorMessage } = this.state;
    return (
        <Paper elevation={4} >
            <Typography type="display2" className="text-center header_title">Connexion</Typography>
            <div className="row content_container">
                <div className="small-4 small-centered columns">
                    <Typography type="body2" className="loginError">{errorMessage}</Typography>
                    <form>
                        <TextField required value={this.state.identifiant} onChange={this.handleIdentifiantChange} label="Identifiant" type="text" className="txtField" marginForm />
                        <TextField required value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} label="Mot de passe" type="password" className="txtField" marginForm />
                        <Button raised color="primary" className=" btn" onClick={this.checkIdentifiantAndPassword}>Se connecter</Button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}
```

};

My problem is, i don't know how to redirect to another component via the **onClick handler**. I tried many solutions like wrapping the **Button** component in a **NavLink** as below:

```
<NavLink to="/new" ><Button raised color="primary" className=" btn" onClick={this.checkIdentifiantAndPassword}>Se connecter</Button></NavLink>
```

but i get an error at the first line of the checkIdentifiantAndPassword method:

```
Cannot read property 'state' of null
```

I know that i can remove the **Button** component and use only **NavLink** and add all the classes of **Button** component to the **NavLink**, but i don't like this workaround.

Do somebody have an idea of how i can achieve this. I am using React-router v4.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<Redirect/>` from 'react-router-dom'.

In the documentation they explain how to use (plus Private Route). See https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow.

I think maybe you can do sth like this:

```
this.state = {
  ....,
  doRedirect: false
}

.....

checkIdentifiantAndPassword(e) {
  .....
  this.setState({
    doRedirect: true
  });
}

.....

render() {
  if (this.state.doRedirect) {
    <Redirect to={/*Your next route*/}/>
  }
  .....
}
```

Comment: Thank you Henrique. I post the whole solution below for others.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Henrique for your response and the link. It was useful.
This is my whole solution for those trying to manage public and private routes with **react-route v4**.

I have 2 private components,1 public component (Connexion) which is the connexion component and a Main component that wraps all these components.

The Connexion component is an id, password fields and a submit button that checks if the connexion is valid.
If yes, the user is routed to a private Component.

I define also 2 other components PublicRoute and PrivateRoute.
The PrivateRoute checks if a user is valid. If yes, route to the appropriate component.

**Main component**

```
class Main extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        login: false
    }
    super(props);

    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
    this.handleDeconnexion = this.handleDeconnexion.bind(this);;
}
handleDeconnexion(value) {
    this.setState({
        login: value
    })
}
handleLogin(isAuthenticated) {
    console.log(isAuthenticated);
    this.setState(
        {
            login: isAuthenticated
        }
    );
}
render() {
    let { login } = this.state;
    return (
        <HashRouter>
            <div>
                <Nav isLoggedIn={login} deconnecter={this.handleDeconnexion} />
                <div className="row main_container">
                    <div className="columns medium-10 small-centered">
                        <PublicRoute exact path="/" component={Connexion} onLogin={this.handleLogin} />
                        <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={login} path="/new" component={Nouveau} />
                        <PrivateRoute isAuthenticated={login} path="/suivi" component={SuiviCas} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </HashRouter>
    );
}
}
```

**Connexion component**

```
class Connexion extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        identifiant: '',
        password: '',
        errorMessage: '',
        doRedirect: false
    };

    this.handleIdentifiantChange = this.handleIdentifiantChange.bind(this);
    this.handlePasswordChange = this.handlePasswordChange.bind(this);
    this.handleLogin = this.handleLogin.bind(this);
}

handleIdentifiantChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        identifiant: e.target.value
    });
}

handlePasswordChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        password: e.target.value
    });
}
handleLogin(e) {
    let { identifiant, password } = this.state;
    if (!identifiant) {
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Identifiant vide ou incorrect.'
        });
        return;
    }
    if (!password) {
        this.setState({
            errorMessage: 'Mot de passe vide ou incorrect.'
        });
        return;
    }
    this.setState({
        doRedirect: true
    });
    this.props.onLogin(true);
}
render() {
    const { from } = this.props.location.state || { from: { pathname: '/thecomponent_you_want_to_redirect_after_login'}
    let{ doRedirect, errorMessage  } = this.state;
    if (doRedirect) {
        return (
            <Redirect to={from} />
        )
    }
    return (
        <Paper elevation={4} >
            <Typography type="display2" className="text-center header_title">Connexion</Typography>
            <div className="row content_container">
                <div className="small-4 small-centered columns">
                    <Typography type="body2" className="loginError">{errorMessage}</Typography>
                    <form>
                        <TextField required value={this.state.identifiant} onChange={this.handleIdentifiantChange} label="Identifiant" type="text" className="txtField" marginForm />
                        <TextField required value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handlePasswordChange} label="Mot de passe" type="password" className="txtField" marginForm />
                        <Button raised color="primary" className=" btn" onClick={this.handleLogin}>Se connecter</Button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Paper>
    );
}
}
```

The **PrivateRoute component** checks if the user is authenticated and redirects to the appropriate route. If not, it routes to the Connexion component.

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, isAuthenticated, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={props => (
    isAuthenticated ? (
        <Component {...props} />
    ) : (
            <Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/',
                state: { from: props.location }
            }} />
        )
)} />
);
```

**PublicRoute component**

```
const PublicRoute = ({ component: Component, onLogin, ...rest }) => (
<Route {...rest} render={props => (

    <Component onLogin={onLogin} {...props} />
)} />
);
```

Here is a useful youtube link explaining react-router v4 and some differences with the v2: [React router v4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UVQ0ATR0vpI).